# What does Timeout.timeout(0) mean in chef server spec (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, rspec, serverspec

I am trying to write server spec code for some service. I want to add the timeout so that if within given time, command doesn't responds, the test case should fail.

When tried for `timeout(0)`, test was passing. Does this mean that there is no timeout?

Code:

```
Timeout.timeout(0) do
  describe 'Check' do
    describe command('echo xxxx | nc localhost xxxx') do
      its(:stdout) { should contain('xxxx') }
      its(:stderr) { should match '' }
    end
  end
end
```

Generally `timeout(0)` or `timeout(-1)` will indicate that there is no timeout. Is it same with serverspec also. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From [`Timeout`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) docs:

> Number of seconds to wait for the block to terminate. Any number may be used, including Floats to specify fractional seconds. **A value of 0 or nil will execute the block without any timeout.**

Emphasis is mine.

Answer (score 0):

It means literally nothing. The other answer is more correct in showing you why, but the tl;dr is that code is useless, probably used to be non-zero when someone was incorrectly trying to make a test with a timeout.